# Directx 12 : Synchronisation between two processes

Tags: c++, directx-12

i have created two application.

One application is rendering a texture off-screen with unlimited frame rate present option.

The second application is reading what APP1 is rendering from graphic memory and rendering/presenting it on window.

currently there is synchronisation issue with this implementation when such frequent updated is performed.

i have shared the fence of APP1 with APP2 and also the texture resource which is to be rendered is shared as well.

i am checking completed value of APP1 fence signaling for wait till completion of APP1 fence value  + 1.

but i am getting

D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Resource1::: CORRUPTION: An ID3D12Resource object (0x0000011055B9BD90:'SharedTextureResource') is referenced by GPU operations in-flight on Command Queue

.... [ EXECUTION ERROR #921: OBJECT_DELETED_WHILE_STILL_IN_USE]

So is it possible to synchronise such implementation in directx 12 with two different application.

so how can we go on with synchronisation of such approach...

thanks.

Comment: First idea:
APP2 waits till APP1 renders to texture.
But does APP1 wait till APP2 presents it?

Comment: Second idea: Do you `OpenSharedHandle` each frame?

Comment: at first i was using OpenSharedHandle each frame and that was crashing and some time working .... later i opened it only once and the begining and things seems to go fine ... however still need to check it further for issues...

Comment: Good, you should call `OpenSharedHandle` only once and then use the same resource. You must be deleting the resource somewhere (by deleting I mean your ComPtr> goes out of scope). Doesn't stack trace get you anywhere?

Comment: yes... issue was .ReleaseAndGetAddressOf() call... causing to free the shared ptr and thus shooting an error....

Comment: i want to confirm one  thing... does it make copy of shared resource in gpu memory...

Comment: Sharing? No, memory is reused, that's the point